# Avoid updating session cookie expire time on request to django

Tags: django, session

I'm trying to ping Django from a javascript frontend to find out when a user's session will expire. I'm doing this so I can proactively notify a user when their session has expired.

Unfortunately, the session expire time is updated because I'm hitting the Django app. I've tried reading the session cookie from javascript, but it is not accessible (nor recommended to be accessible) from javascript.

How can I ping my Django app from javascript to get when the session will end?

Answer (score 1):

What about passing the number of seconds until session will expire directly to your template/javascript? For example, you can get it using [this method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.get_expiry_age) in your view function and pass it further.